# Using supervisord to control the postfix MTA

Tags: postfix

I am trying to use [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#programx) to control postfix. The usual method is to specify a command which starts the daemon, I use `postfix -c /etc/postfix start`. The postfix man page says that to stop you replace `start` with `stop` in the above command.

I do not see a way of specifying another command to stop a daemon, just a signal. The `master` manpage says that the `TERM` signal will function as if `postfix abort` was used but is silent on shutting down gracefully via a signal.

Also, the start/stop method of the first paragraph is tricky as far as supervisord is concerned. The script performs a bunch of checks and then invokes `master`, `qmgr` and `pickup` with `master` as the process group leader. Thus, supervisord has a handle on a useless PID (one the script was running as) and cannot therefore use that PID to stop the daemon. What it should have a handle to is the `master` process.

How far I've got:

```
[program:master]
process_name    = master
priority        = 5
directory       = /etc/postfix
command         = /usr/sbin/postfix -c /etc/postfix start
startsecs       = 0
user            = root
stopsignal      = INT
```

This starts postfix but cannot stop it.

Answer (score 4):

My solution is to write a wrapper script named postfix.sh as follows:

```
# call "postfix stop" when exiting
trap "{ echo Stopping postfix; /usr/sbin/postfix stop; exit 0; }" EXIT

# start postfix
/usr/sbin/postfix -c /etc/postfix start
# avoid exiting
sleep infinity
```

After that, modify supervisord.conf:

```
[program:postfix]
command=path/to/postfix.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that it is simpler to use something like [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) to monitor daemons:

> Monit is a free open source utility for managing and monitoring,
>   processes, programs, files, directories and filesystems on a UNIX
>   system. Monit conducts automatic maintenance and repair and can
>   execute meaningful causal actions in error situations.
>
> You can use Monit to monitor daemon processes or similar programs
>   running on localhost. Monit is particular useful for monitoring daemon
>   processes, such as those started at system boot time from
>   /etc/init.d/. For instance sendmail, sshd, apache and mysql.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The same as @Hui Zheng but checking if posfix is alive

```
trap "postfix stop" SIGINT
trap "postfix stop" SIGTERM
trap "postfix reload" SIGHUP

# force new copy of hosts there (otherwise links could be outdated)
cp /etc/hosts /var/spool/postfix/etc/hosts

# start postfix
postfix start

# lets give postfix some time to start
sleep 3

# wait until postfix is dead (triggered by trap)
while kill -0 "`cat /var/spool/postfix/pid/master.pid`"; do
  sleep 5
done
```

credits goes [here](https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/309436/postfix-wrapper-sh-for-supervisord-in-do)